# Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have just installed Code Blocks together with GNU GCC Compiler. However, when I tried building the first Hello-World program, it keeps showing me this message:

`    -------------- Build: Debug in test1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

```
mingw32-make.exe -Wall -g  -c C:\ProgramData\test1\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\test1.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
mingw32-make.exe: invalid option -- g
mingw32-make.exe: invalid option -- c
Usage: mingw32-make.exe [options] [target] ...
Options:
  -b, -m                      Ignored for compatibility.
  -B, --always-make           Unconditionally make all targets.
  -C DIRECTORY, --directory=DIRECTORY
                          Change to DIRECTORY before doing anything.
  -d                          Print lots of debugging information.
  --debug[=FLAGS]             Print various types of debugging 
information.
  -e, --environment-overrides
                          Environment variables override makefiles.
  --eval=STRING               Evaluate STRING as a makefile statement.
  -f FILE, --file=FILE, --makefile=FILE
                          Read FILE as a makefile.
  -h, --help                  Print this message and exit.
  -i, --ignore-errors         Ignore errors from recipes.
  -I DIRECTORY, --include-dir=DIRECTORY
                          Search DIRECTORY for included makefiles.
  -j [N], --jobs[=N]          Allow N jobs at once; infinite jobs with no arg.
  -k, --keep-going            Keep going when some targets can't be made.
  -l [N], --load-average[=N], --max-load[=N]
                          Don't start multiple jobs unless load is below N.
  -L, --check-symlink-times   Use the latest mtime between symlinks and target.
  -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon
                          Don't actually run any recipe; just print them.
  -o FILE, --old-file=FILE, --assume-old=FILE
                          Consider FILE to be very old and don't remake it.
  -p, --print-data-base       Print make's internal database.
  -q, --question              Run no recipe; exit status says if up to date.
  -r, --no-builtin-rules      Disable the built-in implicit rules.
  -R, --no-builtin-variables  Disable the built-in variable settings.
  -s, --silent, --quiet       Don't echo recipes.
  -S, --no-keep-going, --stop
                          Turns off -k.
  -t, --touch                 Touch targets instead of remaking them.
  --trace                     Print tracing information.
  -v, --version               Print the version number of make and exit.
  -w, --print-directory       Print the current directory.
  --no-print-directory        Turn off -w, even if it was turned on implicitly.
  -W FILE, --what-if=FILE, --new-file=FILE, --assume-new=FILE
                          Consider FILE to be infinitely new.
  --warn-undefined-variables  Warn when an undefined variable is referenced.
This program built for i686-pc-mingw32
Report bugs to <bug-make@gnu.org>
Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))`
```

When I try running the program, it tells me that it hasn't been built yet even though I have already clicked on the Build button, and the console doesn't show. I have tried auto-detecting the compiler, uninstalling and reinstalling Codeblocks but to no avail.
Please suggest a solution as I have been unable to write any programs for a while now.
Thanks,
Mehdi

Comment: Your IDE is misconfigured, it attempts to use `mingw32-make.exe` as a C compiler.

Comment: So what shall I do?